# Trimming spaces out of a string based on a pattern in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a varchar(max) field with XML data in it. I need to clean it by removing the spaces between the tags. For eg:

```
</tns:time_changed>   <tns:changed_properties>
```

should be cleaned as

```
</tns:time_changed><tns:changed_properties>
```

I need to do this in a single query and I cannot use replace all white spaces as there are other relevant spaces in the content.

Comment: I *think* that casting this to a native XML data type will remove the white space

Comment: That is what I orginally wanted to do, but the spaces are causing the error "text/xmldecl not at the beginning of input"

Comment: Sorry, found out that the error was due to the <?xml version="1.0"?>. Removed it and it automatically took care of the spaces. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Converted to XML type and it automatically took care of the spaces. 
Replaced the

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
```

from the field with a blank and it got rid of the error that I was getting "text/xmldecl not at the beginning of input".

Answer (score 0):

Try like this:

```
UPDATE table
SET xmlColumnName = REPLACE ( xmlColumnName , '>   <' , '><' );
```

Comment: The XML do not have a fixed number of spaces between the tags in it, and varies for different tags. I'm looking for somethng like REPLACE (xmlColumnName , [Pattern for '>(n number of spaces)<'], '><');

Comment: Since I think this is one time effort, you can use the above update query with different number of spaces.